# In selenium using the .partition my code only prints what is before the substring not what is after the substring

Tags: python, selenium

In selenium using the .partition my code only prints what is before the substring not what is after the substring.

the response I get is everything before stylecolour it should be everything after

````
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"/Users/husaynjaffer/Desktop/chromedriver")
url = "https://api.nike.com/product_feed/threads/v2/?filter=marketplace%28CA%29&filter=language%28en-GB%29&filter=channelId%28010794e5-35fe-4e32-aaff-cd2c74f89d61%29&filter=exclusiveAccess%28true,false%29"
driver.get(url)
printy= (driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text)





print (printy.partition(",\"styleColor\":\"")[0])```
````

Answer (score 0):

> [**str.partition(*sep*)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)
> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

So `printy.partition(...)[0]` has what is before the separator, and `[2]` will have what's after.